# Why my input is not reseting? {react-router-dom}

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm currently working on getting my reset button to effectively reset the search functionality. While the button itself is working as intended, I'm encountering an issue where the text input field doesn't reset along with it. Strangely, both "query," "searchText," and "inputValue" seem to retain their values, and I'm struggling to find a solution to reset them as well. Any assistance on resolving this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
//This is my reset function
const onResetSearch = () => {
    event.preventDefault();
   setBusco(false);
   setSearchParams({});
   console.log(query, searchText, inputValue);
   onResetForm();
   navigate("/search")}

const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams(); //esto se hace asi nomas
const query = useMemo(() => searchParams.get("q"), [searchParams.get("q")]); 
const heroes = useMemo(() => (query ? getHeroesByName(query) : []), [query]); 
const { searchText, onInputChange, onResetForm } = useForm({searchText: query || ""});

const inputValue = searchText.trim();
const onSearchSubmit = (event) => {
event.preventDefault();
if (inputValue.length < 1 || !inputValue) return;
setSearchParams({ q: inputValue });};

<button onClick={onResetSearch}}
className="btn btn-outline-danger mt-2">Reset</button>
```

When I search something (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQCAr.png)
When I press the reset button (https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCxpt.jpg)
You can see that superman is still there in the input

Comment: There isn't quite enough of the code in its actual unedited form to help here. The snippets appear out of order and cut -- but some of that context is really important here. Where is `useForm` from (what library? Or is it your own impl?).

Comment: I strongly suspect it's because the arguments to `useForm()` are initial values and so, therefore, it will not care when `query` changes and that change was caused by an event outside of the input itself that was not managed by the form lib)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is a little confusing, it looks like you copy and pasted bits and pieces of your code because what you have has lots of issues.

I would like to see how the useSearchParams() is defined. Are you trying to use react hooks here? Why aren't these variables being destructured from useState()? State is how we trigger page renders so this line could be causing your issue:

```
const [searchParams, setSearchParams] = useSearchParams();
```

It would also be helpful to see your JSX for the input field. Resetting a field should be as simple as:

```
<button onClick={() => setMyTextField("")} />
```